# Finding Elements Based on Order

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extract

I am attempting to extract certain elements based on the order they appear in the code. Unfortunately there are some other elements in this webpage that are unneeded. I want to extract `text 1` and `text` and `Text 3` and the second `text` in the example I created below. I'm unable to do this by location like the link below asks because I need to get the elements by a class and element name with
`document.querySelectorAll('.classname b');`
Both elements (the one on the left and the one on the right) need to be accessed this way. How could I do this? Thanks!

Example:

```
<td class="class"><a><img><b>PA3B-2 DESIGN &amp; MANUF WT</b></a></td>
```

then

```
<td class="letter">
100%
<b>A</b>
</td>
```

I want to take out `PA3B-2 DESIGN &amp; MANUF WT` with `A`.
And this repeats except occasionally does not have the 2nd part (class="letter")

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you able to provide some HTML code ?

Comment: no sorry, I will make another example

Comment: provided example code

Comment: Provide a [mcve] there are big gaps in your question, that need a better explanation. Your attempts at explaining things is thorough enough but code says so much more.